# Spring SessionRegistry session id

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I'm trying to extend spring security ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy and override its allowableSessionsExceeded method.

In this method I want to use the sessionInformation.getSessionId() but I get  a different session id then the one I saved during the log in authentication. In the authentication I saved:

```
String sessionId = ((WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails()).getSessionId();
```

Why is it different? What can i do to get the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is sound like, You are saving the earlier sessionId (generated before authentication) and, it gets invalidated after the authentication success.

You will need to get the new sessionId after authentication.

**Update: Better way to get sessionId**

For this, you will need to implement a custom `SessionRegistry`

```
 public class MySessionRegistry implements SessionRegistry{

        @Override
    public SessionInformation getSessionInformation(String sessionId) {
        // this is your session id to be saved
    }

    }
```

And register in the context as

```
<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="com.test.MySessionRegistry">
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: To be sure, I need to use this session id instad of the one after authentication?

Comment: You mean you want to use the same session Id even after successful authentication ?

Comment: I don't understand what the custom sessionregistry is for? were do i need to use it? this changes the sessionInformation.getSessionId()?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You want the sessionId not be changed after login?